# why the class' function doesn't get called in the main?

Tags: c++, class

I wanna create a class that calculates the factorial of an integer number, my code is messed up and I need some orientation... Can you please help me in finding the problem?

```
#include <iostream>

class fact {
private:
    int a;
public:
    fact(){};
    fact(int a){this->a=a;}
    void setfact(int a){this->a=a;}
    int getfact(){return a;}

    int Fact(){
        int i;
        if (a>0){
          for(i=2;i<=a;i++){
            return a=a*i;
          }
        }
        else if (a=0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
     }
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fact b;
    int j;
    cout << "entrer un nombre pour calculer sa factorielle" << endl;
    cin >> j;

    Fact b(j);

    cout << "la factorielle de" << j << "est:" << b.Fact(j);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should I name the parameter in the main function a to call that one in the class?

Comment: `int Fact()` takes no parameters, so `b.Fact(j)` is incorrect.

Comment: Are you required to have a `class` here? This problem can be solved more easily without one.

Comment: `else if (a = 0)` is an accidental assignment. You want `else if (a == 0)` for a comparison.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for your comment! I know I can use this without a class, but next week I have an exam on c++ classes so I wanna prepare myself by being creative... I will do the corrections mentioned thank you

Comment: A `return` statement in a loop that is not protected by some sort of conditional will exit the loop as soon as it is reached.

Comment: Inside `Fact` `a` must have been set. My recommendation: move `fact b;` to after `cin >> j;` and  change it to `fact b(j);` in order to set `b`'s `a` to `j`. If that seems like a confusing mess of alphabet soup, it is. That's one of the downsides of non-descriptive, one letter variable names.

Comment: is it necessary to initialize a new parameter in the `int Fact()` function?

Comment: You need no additional parameters, but when you start debugging `Fact` you will find that you will need an additional local variable.

Comment: I'd recommend you to move `using namespace std;` to the top of your code in case you add a method that uses a std function. Even better, use `std::cout` instead to prevent such errors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, now my code is perfectly working... regardless the soup of variables and declarations hahah.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class fact{
private:
    int a;
public:
    fact(){};
    fact(int a){this->a=a;}
    void setfact(int a){this->a=a;}
    int getfact(){return a;}

    int Fact(int a){
        int i;
        int res=1;
        if (a>0){
            for(i=2;i<=a;i++){
                res=res*i;
            }
          return res;
            }

        else if (a==0)
            return 1;

        else
            return 0;
            }
};


int main()
{

    int j;
    std::cout << "entrer un nombre pour calculer sa factorielle" << endl;
    std::cin >> j;
    fact b(j);

    cout << "la factorielle de " << j << " est: " << b.Fact(j);
    return 0;
}
```